# Animation on emulator slow and choppy due to garbage collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-cursoradapter

I am currently testing my app on an emulator and have noticed a lot of garbage collection takes place while I'm performing animations.

I am concerned that all this garbage collection may not be necessary.

I have a custom cursor adapter:

```
public class AdapterCursorGrid extends CursorAdapter {
```

This adapter populates grid items with `viewflipper`'s.

To recreate the debug below I do the following:

1. Click an item on the first `viewflipper` page
2. This fires an onclick listener and runs `holder.viewFlipper.showNext();`
3. An animation (length 300ms) kicks in which is either non-existent or works poorly
4. Click back on second `viewflipper` page
5. This fires an onclick listener and runs `holder.viewFlipper.showPrevious();`
6. An animation (length 300ms) kicks in which is very choppy if not non-existent.

The debug appears as below:

```
/* 
 * Step 1. Click an item on the first `viewflipper` page
 */
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1628K, 20% free 11041K/13767K,    paused 74ms    
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 16% free 11662K/13767K, paused 6ms+16ms    
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 13% free 12081K/13767K, paused 45ms+6ms

/* 
 * Step 4. Click back on second `viewflipper` page
 */
I/ContentManager(15415): Update() record
I/AdapterCursorGrid(15415): bindView()
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1448K, 19% free 11237K/13767K, paused 69ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 14% free 11855K/13767K, paused 8ms+11ms
I/AdapterCursorGrid(15415): bindView()
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 11% free 12274K/13767K, paused 14ms+10ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1241K, 19% free 11231K/13767K, paused 142ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 14% free 11855K/13767K, paused 7ms+7ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 455K, 11% free 12274K/13767K, paused 5ms+12ms
I/AdapterCursorGrid(15415): bindView()
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1242K, 19% free 11232K/13767K, paused 69ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 14% free 11855K/13767K, paused 5ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm(15415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 455K, 11% free 12274K/13767K, paused 5ms+12ms
```

From the debug you can probably work out that I perform an update in step 4. This is a called to my content provider and is done off the ui thread.

Finally, the `viewflipper` has a semi-complex layout which consists of a relative layout with various `ImageView`s and `TextView`s floating about. 3 `TextView`s, 2/3 `ImageViews`.

An example of an `ImageView` being populated in `bindView` is as follows:

```
/*
 * Set picture
 */
int pictureColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyTable.TABLE_COLUMN_PICTURE);
byte[] picture = cursor.getBlob(pictureColumnIndex);
Bitmap bitmapPicture = null;
if (!cursor.isNull(pictureColumnIndex) && picture.length > 0) {

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(picture);
    bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    bitmapPicture = ImageUtils.scaleBitmap(context,bitmapPicture,ConversionUtils.convertDpToPixels(context, mResources.getDimension(R.dimen.grid_item_width_pic_resize)));
    bitmapPicture = ImageUtils.roundedBitmapCorners(bitmapPicture, ConversionUtils.convertDpToPixels(context, 2));

    holder.imageViewPicture.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPicture));
} else {
    holder.imageViewPicture.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is `bindView` called more than 1 time (called 3 times in step 4)?
2. What could be creating all the GC calls?

Comment: "Why is bindView called" ... you have to learn how Adapters work in Android ... Adapters are smart ... they are trying to reuse old Views ... next storing pictures as blobs it isn't a good thing ... it will be easy to use some kind of ImageLoader implementation if you will store path to image in db and image somewhere on "disk" ...

Comment: Setting the width (or height) of a ListView to wrap_content will cause it to measure the first 3 items.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak My GridView is set to fill_parent for both.

Comment: "What could be creating all the GC calls?" : You're creating three `bitmapPicture`s in a row, then ditching two of them. GC is what happens to them.

Comment: @Selvin The image implementaion has been chosen as a blob for ease of storage and for database synchronisation reasons. Although, this could be achieved your way just not quite as easily (imo). The image in this situation is small (96px).

Comment: @Geobits ok, is there a better way? Maybe I should be caching this image once created and using the cached version until it changes?

Comment: @Selvin "Why is bindView called more than 1 time?", that's my actual question! Why is it being call 3 times and not just once?